# Is resigning justifiable when the employer has broken trust

Tags: resignation, employer-relations

I'm in an employment arrangement I'm not happy with. To be fair, I didn't enter it expecting some dream job, but neither did I enter it expecting it to decline so rapidly.

Six months ago I took on a contract for a major financial institution and I was brought on under the expectation of a .Net developer. Long story short, I spent the first four months working in an archaic system (circa 1978) and handling mainframe configuration issues, not working in my area of strength.

During my contract period, my value was assessed based on areas I'm not an expert in. At conversion, HR presented me with an offer letter $25k below my agreed conversion rate during the interview process. I declined it and was able to recoup some salary but still ending up taking a $14K cut. Subsequently they have undergone 2 rounds of layoffs in the last month and my manager outright said he does not trust me to work from home despite knowing that I previously worked on sensitive gov't projects, often remote worked without any prior issues and provided excellent references during the interview process to my ability to be productive in and out of the office.  He and other people on his team routinely remote work 3 days a week.

Looking back at

1. I was not informed I'd be working almost exclusively on archaic systems and technologies not mentioned in the interview process
2. My manager and HR tried to significantly undercut my agreed conversion salary rate
3. My manager flat out saying he doesn't trust me to remote work and the layoffs that have occurred, the whole environment has felt toxic and created a strong distrust.

Whether it be in this organization or any other, do these conditions justify an individual resigning and/or moving on to something else?

Comment: You don't need to justify a resignation to anyone but yourself. Find a new position and leave this one.

Comment: Because it  had to do with timing of things in my life and also I was offered a bonus to make up some of it. However I found out after the fact bonus payouts may end up being deferred ( related to those layoffs that have occurred since I converted) so if I resign before then I'd never see that money obviously.

Comment: Don't stick with this job in the hope of a bonus unless there is a contracted amount and date.

Comment: You never need a justification to resign.  The real question is why you signed on in the first place.  Its one thing to low ball an offer.  Its another to agree to one rate and send another in the offer.  That alone means they're untrustworthy and you should look elsewhere.

Comment: Ultimately, you are the only one who can decide that.  PERSONALLY, I'd be looking for the next job, with the intention of getting the bleep outta that sh*thole as soon as possible, if not sooner.

Comment: For some shady businesses, this is their employment model. Throw programmers, for a cut-rate trial period, into a situation where they have no training, support or anything that will help them do the job.  Then, at the end of the trial period, offer to extend at the cut-rate since the value hasn't been demonstrated, or offer to meet half way (still way below market value), knowing the person will refuse, and they can move on to the next wave of "trial period" contractors. Had it happen to me with a classic ASP position for a very, very shady "credit protection services" company.

Answer (score 26):

You don't need to "justify" resigning to anybody. When you no longer want to continue the job, just hand in your resignation and leave (after serving the notice period, if applicable).

Once you are out of the company, what happens to them or how they react to your leaving or how your leaving affects them is none of your business.